Clicking nav link teleports to section and does not auto scroll
I am trying to implement auto scroll but it does not scroll – it simply teleports to the section. I have already added the ID of the section to each section and have used the Tailwind class of scroll-smooth on my HTML element.
My main component
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className={`px-20 flex flex-col gap-96 text-white font-sans`}>
      <HomePage/>
      <About/>
      <Projects/>
      <Skills/>
      <Contact/>
    </main>
  );
}

This is the main rootLayout:
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className="!scroll-smooth">
      <body className={firacode.className}>
        <ActiveSectionContextProvider>
          <Header/>
          {children}
          <Footer/>
        </ActiveSectionContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

What could be the reason why it is not scrolling?
I tried using the Tailwind class of className="!scroll-smooth" but it did not change anything.
